# Database-safe Concurrency in ROR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, concurrency

Trying to figure out how concurrency is dealt with in Ruby On Rails.

How do I get a segment of code to lock on lines in the database and force rollbacks when needed?

More specificly, **Is there a way to force a certain segment of code to complete totally and if not rollback?** I'm looking to add history to transactions in my project and I don't want transactions to commit without the history being saved so if the server falls between the two actions (saving the transaction and saving the history) the database may go into an illegal state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to look at [ActiveRecord Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) and [Pessimistic Locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html).

```
Account.transaction do
  account = Account.find(account_id)
  account.lock!

  if account.balance >= 100
    account.balance -= 100
    account.save
  end
end
```

Comment: can if statements on the database be done within the transaction too?

Comment: Anything you want can go within the transaction block, so yes, if statements can be done.

Comment: and if by the end the if would have failed by something changing from a different transaction?

Comment: The transaction will make sure your operations happen atomically, regardless of what data is changed elsewhere.

Comment: Not sure you got my question, if I want to check if I have money in the bank before i withdraw and after i check someone else withdraws and then I withdraw that might put me in an illigal state... how do i stop that?

Comment: Ah. You should lock the pertinent rows in the table before you check the balance and do the withdrawal if appropriate. I have updated mu answer with an example and a link to the Pessimistic locking docs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4497/discussion-between-douglas-f-shearer-and-nayish)

Comment: Great! Chat was me clicking on a link by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have a way of implementing a transaction in Rails. An example:

```
YourModel.transaction do
  rec1.save!
  rec2.save!
end
```

More info [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)